# What's a good onomatopoeia for “suddenly realizing, in a flash of genius”?

Tags: word-requests, onomatopoeia

In a sentence like:

> While I was in the bath, **(suddenly / in a flash of genius / …)** I thought of a great plan.
>
> 風呂に入っている時に、**____と**すごい計画を思いついた。

Is there a good [擬情語]{gijōgo} word to fill in the blanks with? Is something like **パッと** okay?

Comment: [ピカッと](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=ひらめく)...

Comment: 「[閃く]{ひらめく}」っても確かに役に立つ言葉です。教えてくれてありがとう^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most common (and versatile as well) one for us native speakers would be:

- 「ふと」 or
- 「ふっと」

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/193987/meaning/m0u/

「パッと」 is not a bad choice, either.  It just  sounds lighter and more conversational than 「ふと」.

EDIT: 「はっと」 is also a common one.

Comment: can we use いきなり in this circumstances ?

Comment: I don't think いきなり is considered as onomatopoeia though.

Comment: I think いきなり suits my example just fine, but I am trying to use more onomatopoeic words in my Japanese, which is why I asked the question the way I did.